# How to add a calculated/computed column in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, calculated-columns

Suppose I have a numpy array:

```
1 10
2 20
3 0
4 30
```

and I want to add a third column where each row is the sum (or some arbitrary calculation) of the first two columns in that row:

```
1 10 11
2 20 22
3 0  3
4 30 34
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

For these kinds of calculations the built-in [map function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) is very useful.  It only remains to add the result of the calculation to the third column.  For summing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> my_arr = np.array([[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 0], [4, 30]])
>>> np.vstack( (my_arr.T, map(sum, my_arr) )).T
array([[ 1, 10, 11],
       [ 2, 20, 22],
       [ 3,  0,  3],
       [ 4, 30, 34]])
```

It also works with other functions:

```
>>> my_func = lambda x: 2*x[0] + x[1]
>>> np.vstack( (my_arr.T, map(my_func, my_arr) )).T
array([[ 1, 10, 12],
       [ 2, 20, 24],
       [ 3,  0,  6],
       [ 4, 30, 38]])
```

Comment: got error: `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy

my_arr = numpy.array([[1, 10],
                      [2, 20],
                      [3, 0],
                      [4, 30]])
column0 = my_arr[:,0:1]  # Use 0:1 as a dummy slice to maintain a 2d array
column1 = my_arr[:,1:2]  # Use 1:2 as a dummy slice to maintain a 2d array
new_column = column0 + column1
my_arr = numpy.hstack((my_arr, new_column))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

Note np.sum along axis 1 would add the elements row wise.
You can then reshape the result as a column matrix and finally append to the original array

```
>>> new_col = np.sum(x,1).reshape((x.shape[0],1))
>>> np.append(x,new_col,1)
array([[ 1, 10, 11],
       [ 2, 20, 22],
       [ 3, 30, 33],
       [ 4, 40, 44]])
```

or in a single line

```
np.append(x,np.sum(x,1).reshape((x.shape[0],1)),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

almost new to numpy. looking for a solution to the same question I found this that seems quite linear:

```
import numpy as np
my_arr = np.array([[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 0], [4, 30]])
my_func = lambda x: 2*x[0] + x[1]
new_col = np.apply_along_axis(my_func, axis = 1, arr = my_arr)
my_arr = np.column_stack((my_arr, new_col))

my_arr
array([[ 1, 10, 12],
       [ 2, 20, 24],
       [ 3,  0,  6],
       [ 4, 30, 38]])
```

maybe apply_along_axis was not available in 2012?